# Jupyter notebook cell is stuck on [*], ran twice then stopped working

Tags: python, jupyter

I am trying to run the following snippet of code in a Jupyter notebook cell. What I find odd, is that I was able to output the graph twice, then suddenly, without any changes to the code, running the cell just produces a [*] and no output.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

greyhounds = 500
labs = 500

# Average height of dog +/- 4 inches
grey_height = 28 + 4 * np.random.randn(greyhounds)
lab_height = 24 + 4 * np.random.randn(labs)

# greyHounds=red & labs=blue
plt.hist([grey_height, lab_height], stacked=True, color=['r','b'])
plt.show()

! python
```

I've tried resetting the notebook, did not work.

Comment: What's the last "! python" bit at the end?

Comment: Looks like possibly trying to import something, and possibly attempting to import python each time?

Comment: To my understanding, your `! python` is spawning an uninterrupted python process, just like what happens when you enter `python` in a command line. Take it off and it's done.

Comment: The bit at the end, ! python, shouldn't break the cell. It just simulates a terminal command. 
I think the issue is that I saved the notebook to a new location, I think shortly after that the problem started, although not immediately. Resetting the kernel seems to help temporarily. It's a bit tricky, still trying to figure out exactly how this can be resolved.